# Mathjax and cumulative layout shift

Tags: mathjax

Recently google introduced CLS - cumulative layout shift. Mathjax formulas change the CLS. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Dear Andrew, did MathJax lazy extension do the trick or did you find some other solution?

Comment: Anyhow, I have outlined my solution on this page: https://robertfilter.net/blog/webtech/how-to-solve-mathjax-cumulative-layout-shift.html Maybe you find it sufficient for your needs :)

Comment: @RobertFilter , I used lazy typesetting (onclick/onscroll).

Answer (score 1):

MathJax v3.2 has an extension that does lazy typesetting (only typesets the expressions as they come into view).  As a side effect of that, the position doesn't change due to expressions being typeset above the current view location.  You might try upgrading to v3.2 and include the [lazy extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/whats-new-3.2.html#v3-2-lazy-typesetting) in your configuration.